# Ubuntu 18 keeps processes running

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-gnome, process

I noticed my Ubuntu keeps process running after ending an application. For instance after closing my vscode it still appears to be in the process and still takes up memory and I end up having multiple processes of any application I open and close . It slows down my laptop after a while. How can I kill the process once I close an application?

Answer (score 0):

You might try `ps aux | grep processName` which gives the following

```
User    pid  0.6  0.1 929660  9756 ?        Rl   12:40   4:31 conky
User    pid  0.0  0.0   9124  1008 pts/1    S+   23:27   0:00 grep --color=auto conky
```

then you can issue `sudo kill -9 pid`

However processes not closing properyly may be more of an issues than just wanting to kill them. What is the output of `journalctl -f` when closing a process?

**Edit:** Do not however frivolously kill processes however this is not always a good idea, as you may (like I have many times) kill the wrong process and not realize it

Comment: My problem is that when I close an app it still appears in system monitor . If I have used the app more than once then it appears the number of times that I have used the app and it still takes up memory space

Comment: it still appears in top? are you able to kill it with the aforementioned suggestion? Also have you checked the journal around the time you try to close the apps?